# Replacing objects in ListView - JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx

When I'm adding File type objects to a ListView, they are replaced.
I don't know how to handle with that.

Methods that operates on the ListView are: `save()` and `cellFactory()`.

[Here is code.](https://pastebin.com/dXqQVd6r)

```
@FXML
private Button folderButton;
@FXML
private TextField fileDirectory;
@FXML
private TextField fileName;
@FXML
private Button saveButton;
```

Comment: We require the question itself to contain a [mcve]/enough the code explaining the situatuation AND a description of your issue. (I've trouble understanding what *"they are replaced"* means here.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I would suggest you to paste and format code inside question, this way it will stay relevant so other users can find your question more helpful.

Problem in your code is most likely at line 56, there you wrote:

`listView.getItems().setAll(selectedFile);`

In [javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/collections/ObservableList.html#setAll-java.util.Collection-) it says this about method:

> Clears the ObservableList and add all elements from the collection.

Instead use `addAll` method, or if you know it is only 1 element then use just `add`.